# How to get JSON Key and Values using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to get below `JSON` result of `Key` and `Value` and store it into two separate arrays `(keyArray and valuesArray)`. Keys I can append easily but values not appending. It's showing

> error 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?`.

JSON Keys are string but value is Int. How to append Int into string array?

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": “ranking”,
    "result": {
        "cost": 150,
        "discount": 25,
        “fixon": 0,
        "fee": 0,
        "check": 0,
        "mailing": 20,
    }
}
```

I tried

```
 for (key, value) in results {
    print("key (key) value2 (value)")
    self.processtitle.append(key)
    self.price.append(value) as! String? //'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
 }
```

Comment: Don't use separate arrays. Decode the JSON into structs with `Decodable`. And JSON is never `AnyObject` in Swift 3+ unless you use typeless `NS...` classes.

Comment: please tell about NS...@vadian decodable I can't able to use because result of keys have chance to increase and decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear you can't parse JSON by this way , so you can parse JSON by Decodable

But for pass this error you can add a condition:

```
if let key = key {
   self.processtitle.append(key)
}
if let value = value {
   self.price.append("\(value)")
}
```

Comment: Great help. Thank you so much @Abdulameer. I am doing decodable but time being I am going to use this. Thanks a lot